# How can I show only zombie processes in htop?

Tags: 16.04, htop, zombie

I would like to monitor in real time zombie process in htop?

Comment: There is a contradiction there: zombies are processes that got disconnected and as will not have a process to monitor. `ps aux | awk '"[Zz]" ~ $8 { printf("%s, PID = %d\n", $8, $2); }'`  will list zombies but I do not believe you can use htop for that.

Answer (score 6):

You should click on `S` column or choose <kbd>F6</kbd> (`SortBy`) and then select `STATE`.

Afterwards you will get zombies on top:

[image: Htop with Zombies]